# ”what should be long past his bedtime“ meaning in this context?

Tags: reading-comprehension

> Dan Rather
>   @DanRather
>   This is apparently what the President of the United States feels the need to share with the world at **what should be long past his bedtime**? It's a disgrace. It's racist. And it's the product of petty but dangerous hatreds. I repeat this is the PRESIDENT??!?
>
> > Donald J. Trump
> >     @realDonaldTrump
> >     Lebron James was just interviewed by the dumbest man on television, Don Lemon. He made Lebron look smart, which isn’t easy to do. I like Mike!

I came across this tweet in this article: [Celebs – and the first lady – are reacting to President Trump’s tweet about LeBron James, and no one’s happy](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/celebs-journalists-reacting-president-trumps-tweet-lebron-james-no-ones-happy-172855389.html).

I don't quite understand "**what should be long past his bedtime**". I figure it refers to something that the President thought through his bedtime. But I have no confidence about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What should be his bedtime* is some time by which he should be asleep, for example 10 pm.

*What should be long past his bedtime* is some time long after the time by which he should be asleep, for example 2 am.

The writer is continuing a joke about Trump. Trump has a history of late-night Twitter rants.

> “I like three hours, four hours, I toss, I turn, I beep-de-beep, I want to find out what’s going on,” he said last year in Illinois. But instead of picking up a paper, he’s now more likely to indulge a new early-morning vice—off-the-cuff tweeting. (That might be the “beep-de-beep” he’s talking about.)
>
> Some of @RealDonaldTrump’s nocturnal submissions have made the news: His slams against Megyn Kelly (3:53 a.m.), accusations that Ted Cruz committed fraud in Iowa (1:38 a.m.), the denunciation of Alicia Machado (5:30 a.m.). They’re also a series of valuable data points about a presidential candidate’s sleep cycle—a ping that, yes, Donald Trump is awake and restless.

Source: [What Trump Tweets While America Sleeps](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2016/10/what-trump-tweets-while-america-sleeps/503141/)

He's often ridiculed for this behavior.

Comment: Does it also have the implication "acting like an over-tired child" as pointed out in the other answers?

Comment: You could argue that. I didn’t read into it that deeply. I just read it as he should have been sleeping instead of tweeting.

Answer (score 1):

When children are excessively tired because they have been allowed to stay up beyond their regular bedtime, they may behave in annoying or silly ways, including making ill-judged or stupid remarks. The person whom you quote intended to convey the opinion that the President was acting like an over-tired child who should have gone to bed a long time before.

Comment: Can you help to explain it in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. But shouldn't it be  _at what should **have been** long past his bedtime?_

Comment: Present tense matching: 'what the President **feels**' ... at what should **be** long past his bedtime'.